# How to count all the users that are currently logged In ? (Django rest framework)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am currently trying to count the users that are currently logged in.
I tried many things but none of them works.

The last code that i tried is :

```
def count_currently_logged_in(request):
    count = Profile.objects.filter(last_login__startswith=timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(minutes=20)).count()
    return Response(count, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your profile contains a `DateTimeField` named `last_login` (this seems to be the case here), you can count this with:

```
from django.utils import timezone

def count_currently_logged_in(request):
    ago20m = timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(minutes=20)
    count = Profile.objects.filter(last_login__gte=ago20m).count()
    return Response(count, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

We thus filter the `Profile`s to retain only profiles with a `last_login` *later* than or exactly 20 minutes ago, and we count these profiles.

Comment: It counts all the users that logged in in the last 20 minutes. However I would like to know if it's possible to count the users that are currently logged in ( check if their jwt token is valid ? )

Comment: @Reda: what system do you use for that? How is it stored in the "models"?